# Kotlin - use action parameter in repeat function

Tags: kotlin

I know how to pass times as the first parameter of `repeat` function:

```
repeat(3) {
  println("This will print 3 times")
}
```

But I checked Kotlin documentation, it shows there's another parameter `action` to use(see [kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html)):

```
inline fun repeat(times: Int, action: (Int) -> Unit)
```

I tried this code but failed with the error *Expecting ')'*:

```
repeat(3, 2 -> anotherFun()) {
    println("This will show 2 times?")
}

fun anotherFun() {
    println("head into the 2nd time and print this out.")
}
```

I know I have got the syntax error. so my question is: what is `(Int) -> Unit` and how to use the action parameter properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is (Int) -> Unit and how to use the action parameter properly?

`(Int) -> Unit` describes a function that takes an `Int` and returns `Unit` (void). In order to call it as-is, you can do it like this:

```
repeat(3, {anotherFunction()})
```

Or

```
repeat(3) {
    anotherFunction()
}
```

However, the number of iterations that will happen is not available, but you could define your own by borrowing from the one in the standard library...

```
public inline fun repeat(times: Int, action: (Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    for (index in 0 until times) {
        action(times, index)
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
repeat(3) { times, i ->
    println("Called $i/$times")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

I'm still confused about this:

(Int) -> Unit describes a function that takes an Int and returns Unit (void).

But when I try to use `repeat(3, {anotherFunction()})`, it seems `anotherFunction()` is not taking any `Int` parameters?

Comment: @shisaq I'll write your function call more explicitly: `repeat(3, { it: Int -> anotherFunction()})` You call a function from a lambda. You have the Int parameter available but you never use it.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks! This helped me a lot! I got the proper syntax and have known how to pass the parameter to `anotherFunction`: `repeat(3, { it: Int -> anotherFunction(it)})`. The reason I made the mistake is that I'm not familiar with lambda.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I have got the syntax error. so my question is: what is (Int)
>   -> Unit and how to use the action parameter properly?

```
repeat(3) {
    println("This will print 3 times, $it cycle number")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the overall number of iterations within the lambda, you can declare a variable (`val`) outside of it beforehand as well:

```
val i = 3
repeat(i) {
    println("iteration $it of $i")
}
```