# How to use validation if I am not selecting any images in multiple Images

Tags: android, image, validation, kotlin, android-networking

I need a suggestion if the user does not select any images but I need to pass in parameters of API how to resolve this :

```
   AndroidNetworking.upload(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=editprofile")
           .addMultipartFile("image", imageFileOne)
           .addMultipartFile("image1", imagesFiles[0])
        .addMultipartFile("image2", imagesFiles[1])
        .addMultipartFile("image3", imagesFiles[2])
        .addMultipartFile("image4", imagesFiles[3])
        .addMultipartFile("image5", imagesFiles[4])
        .addMultipartFile("image6", imagesFiles[5])

        .addMultipartParameter("userid", usetId)
        .addMultipartParameter("username", binding.etName.text.toString())
        .addMultipartParameter("bio", binding.etBio.text.toString())
        .addMultipartParameter("education", binding.etBio.text.toString())
        .addMultipartParameter("dob", binding.etDob.text.toString())
        .addMultipartParameter("city", binding.etHomeTown.text.toString())
        .addMultipartParameter("fb_link", binding.etFbLink.text.toString())
       .addMultipartParameter("image_size",sizeArray.toString())
        .addMultipartFileList(mMultiPartFileMap)
        .setTag("editprofile")
        .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
        .build()
        .getAsString(object : StringRequestListener {
            override fun onResponse(response: String) {
                Log.d("@@image2", imagesFiles.toString())
                Log.d("@@res", response)
                Log.d("@@imagesFiles", imagesFiles[0].toString())

                var gson: Gson = Gson()
                var updateProfileModel = gson.fromJson(response, UpdateProfile::class.java)
                if (updateProfileModel.error == false) {
                    if (updateProfileModel.data != null) {
                        MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!!.data!!.image =
                            updateProfileModel.data.image
                    } else {
                        AppLogger.toast("Something went wrong")
                    }
                    AppLogger.toast(updateProfileModel.message)

                } else {
                    AppLogger.toast(updateProfileModel.message)
                }
                binding.progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
            }

            override fun onError(error: ANError) {
                binding.progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
                // handle error
                AppLogger.toast(error.localizedMessage)
                Log.e(" MoodMatc honError", "=======" + error.localizedMessage)
            }
        })
}
```

how to resolve this if the user does not select anyone images or a single image.

here is onactivity result code when select images :

```
 public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_MAIN_PICTURE) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteMainImageUri = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteMainImageUri != null) {
                binding.mainUserImage.setImageURI(selecteMainImageUri)
                Log.e("@@selecteMain", selecteMainImageUri.toString())
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_1) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri_1 = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            Log.e("@@selecteImageUri_1", selecteImageUri_1.toString())

            if (selecteImageUri_1 != null) {
                binding.ivOther1.setImageURI(selecteImageUri_1)
            }
             else {
                binding.ivOther1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(""))

            }


        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_2) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri_2 = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteImageUri_2 != null) {
                binding.ivOther2.setImageURI(selecteImageUri_2)
            }

            else {
                binding.ivOther2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(""))

            }
            Log.e("@@selecteImage2", selecteImageUri_2.toString())

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_3) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri_3 = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteImageUri_3 != null) {
                binding.ivOther3.setImageURI(selecteImageUri_3)
            }

            else {
                binding.ivOther3.setImageURI(Uri.parse(""))

            }

            Log.e("@@selecteImage3", selecteImageUri_3.toString())


        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_4) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri_4 = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteImageUri_4 != null) {
                binding.ivOther4.setImageURI(selecteImageUri_4)
            }

            else {
                binding.ivOther4.setImageURI(Uri.parse(""))

            }

            Log.e("@@selecteImage4", selecteImageUri_4.toString())

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_5) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri_5 = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteImageUri_5 != null) {
                binding.ivOther5.setImageURI(selecteImageUri_5)
            }

            else {
                binding.ivOther5.setImageURI(Uri.parse(""))

            }

            Log.e("@@selecteImage5", selecteImageUri_5.toString())

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_6) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri_6 = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteImageUri_6 != null) {
                binding.ivOther6.setImageURI(selecteImageUri_6)
            }

            else {
                binding.ivOther6.setImageURI(Uri.parse(""))

            }
            Log.e("@@selecteImage5", selecteImageUri_6.toString())

        }

    }
}
```

I am always getting the error in param pass

```
 .addMultipartFile("image1", imagesFiles[0])
        .addMultipartFile("image2", imagesFiles[1])
        .addMultipartFile("image3", imagesFiles[2])
        .addMultipartFile("image4", imagesFiles[3])
        .addMultipartFile("image5", imagesFiles[4])
        .addMultipartFile("image6", imagesFiles[5])
```

How to resolve this Please help me thank you in advance I would appreciate every answer and suggestion

Comment: getting the error in imagesFiles array list because of size

Comment: Try this. First check size of imagesFiles

    if(imagesFiles.size()>0){
     if(imagesFiles[0]==null){
     < you have select no file>
       }
    }

Comment: where I need to use this

Comment: Above this line - .addMultipartFile("image1", imagesFiles[0])

Comment: here if condition is not applicable to add

Comment: here if condition is not allowed to add after . dot

Comment: Put these 6 values (imagesFiles[0]) in 6 strings and above  AndroidNetworking.upload check weather they are null or not if yes pass blank sting else pass whatever it contains

Comment: String first = imagesFiles[0]; if(first.equalIgnoreCase("null")){first =""} and   here .addMultipartFile("image1", first)

Answer (score 0):

```
val uploadImage=AndroidNetworking.upload(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=editprofile") 
repeat(imagesFiles.size){
        uploadImage.addMultipartFile("image${it+1}", imagesFiles[it])

}
```

Comment: what is a repeat  here?

Comment: repeat is kotlin function . for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/50341140/9315408

Comment: it is asking to create a new function

Comment: and what is "it"

Comment: it is the index of array

Comment: var it = 0

        val uploadImage=AndroidNetworking.upload(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=editprofile")
        repeat(imagesFiles.size){
            uploadImage.addMultipartFile("image${it+1}", imagesFiles[it])
            it++

        }

Comment: it is by default its not var

Comment: var it = 0

        val uploadImage=AndroidNetworking.upload(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=editprofile")
        repeat(imagesFiles.size){
            uploadImage.addMultipartFile("image${it+1}", imagesFiles[it])

        }
        it++

Comment: val uploadImage=AndroidNetworking.upload(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=editprofile")
repeat(imagesFiles.size){index->
    uploadImage.addMultipartFile("image${index+1}", imagesFiles[index])
}

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks